# how do I read the second argument in > ./b.sh /net/*

Tags: bash, shell

here is what my professor wants

> ./b.sh /net/*

```
       12 /net/aquota.user
    15751 /net/slackware.iso
```

here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in $1/*
do
  if test -f "${FILE}"
  then
    inode=$(stat -c %i ${FILE})
    echo $inode $FILE
  fi
done
```

I know how to read it with $1 when it is /net, but my professor wants users to type /net/*, what should I change?

Comment: `/net/*` would be expanded by the shell, turning the command into `./b.sh /net/file1 /net/file2 /net/file3 etc...`

Comment: To extend Marc's comment, you want to iterate over *all* the positional parameters. Or, pass all the parameters to `stat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell expands `net/*` before your script runs, so you are getting more than one argument, and simply need to loop over them.

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE; do                # or for FILE in "$@"; do
  if test -f "${FILE}"      # not really necessary or useful
  then
    inode=$(stat -c %i "${FILE}")
    echo "$inode" "$FILE"   # not really necessary or useful
  fi
done
```

or more succinctly

```
stat -c '%i %n' "$@"
```